# Redirect many domains to different locations of other domain with nginx without having to define many server blocks

Tags: nginx, domain-name, 301-redirect

Say i have multiple variations on a domain name, one *brandname* registered at multiple top-level domains; and they all need to go to one specific domain + append a dedicated custom uri that relates to the originally requested domain.

For example i have:

- domain.tld
- domain.net
- domain.org
- domain.com

Where **domain.com** is the one where all requests need to land after appending an extra uri like this:

- domain.com/tld
- domain.com/net
- domain.com/org

I came up with this working setup:

```
# (www.)domain.tld
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;
        return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com/tld$request_uri;
}

# (www.)domain.net
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name domain.net www.domain.net;
        return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com/net$request_uri;
}

# (www.)domain.org
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name domain.org www.domain.org;
        return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com/org$request_uri;
}


# (www.)domain.com
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name domain.org www.domain.org;

        location / {
               proxy_set_header        Host $host;
               proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
               proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
               proxy_pass              http://backend.host:port;
          }

}
```

But the declaration of multiple *server* blocks, although logical, looks  over-verbose.

**TL;DR**
Are there ways to accomplish this kind of redirecting without having to define a **server** block for each domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular expression `server_name` directive can capture the last element of the domain name for use in the redirect. For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~\.(?<tld>[^.]+)$;
    return 301 $scheme://www.domain.com/$tld$request_uri;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for details.

Comment: Sweet, this is way more elegant than the long-form solution i came up with. Thanks @richard-smith :)